# JSFL Delete Unused Library Items

Tags: jsfl

Does JFSL code exist for deleting unused library items in flash?

I know you can select "Unused Items" from the Flash library menu then simply hit the delete key. This is fine but I would like to automate this process as I have to repeat this for several projects.

Thanks In advance!

-PAT

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but this works for me:

```
 var dom = fl.getDocumentDOM();
 var items = dom.library.items;
 var lib= dom.library;

 //Look for Assets folder and remove

 for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
 {     
      if (items[i].name.indexOf("Assets") >= 0)
      {
         fl.trace(items[i].name+ " - target item found: Deleted");
         lib.deleteItem(items[i].name);
      }
 }
```

You can also remove an item based on type:

```
  for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
   {
      if (items[i].itemType=="graphic")
      {
         lib.deleteItem(items[i].name);
      } 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right and remove unused items is not available. 
In the past there was also a select and compact option that is no longer available.

So the best solution I could find was creating a new document and copy paste everything that is on the stage into the new doc. 
Its not ideal and wont work for everything but it will work for some projects. 
You can find the code here: 
[in this AS3 code blog](http://as3.ingogoland.com/function/how-to-delete-unused-library-files-with-jsfl-in-cs5/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Per the FAQ, you need to disclose that your association with the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on the previous suggestion, sometimes you find when you delete something that's unused, another thing becomes unused.  I wrote some code that loops thru until everything that's unused is finally deleted.  You can just remove the while loop if you don't need the recursive aspect.

```
var lib = fl.getDocumentDOM().library;

while(lib.unusedItems.length > 0)
{
    fl.trace("Deleting... " + lib.unusedItems.length + " items");
    var unusedArr = lib.unusedItems;

    for(var i=0;i<unusedArr.length;i++) 
    {
        var unused = unusedArr[i];
        fl.trace("  deleting " + unused.name);
        lib.deleteItem(unused.name);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2011/02/23/creating-flash-extensions-pt-3-manipulating-the-library/) is the tutorial for managing and maintaining the library, using this you can easily delete the unused items. Just follow the steps for creating a JFSL file as mentioned in tutorial

Comment: Thanks NIlesh for the response. I read through this tutorial and did not find anything on the subjuct of using JSFL for Removing Unused Items. However, in the first paragraph the author mentions this as quality of a good collaborator. That is, a person who is "naming layers and library items clearly, deleting unused material, keeping folders organized" Rats! I really wanted this tut. to work for me!  I'm begging to start to believe that Removing Unused Items through JSFL is a functionality that Adobe overlooked or decided against. Thanks again for the response! -Pat

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked and answered here:

[Checking 'Use Count' for library items with JSFL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664899/checking-use-count-for-library-items-with-jsfl)

Since then there has been a bit of an update.  Flash Professional CC was released and there is a new JSAPI for this finally. The info is located here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS849c47c2a95c1007-6e6f2af913b0a89ffd8-8000.html

***NOTE*** - library.unusedItems is only available in Flash Professional CC.

Answer (score 0):

This simple script will do the job in Flash Pro CC

```
var unusedArr = fl.getDocumentDOM().library.unusedItems;

for(var i=0;i<unusedArr.length;i++) {
    fl.trace('Item removed: '+unusedArr[i].name);
    fl.getDocumentDOM().library.deleteItem(unusedArr[i].name);
}

fl.trace(unusedArr.length+' Items removed');
```